# structure padding alignment?

Tags: c, linux

```
typedef struct structc_tag
{
   char        c;
   double      d;
   int         s;
} structc_t;
```

Applying same analysis, structc_t needs sizeof(char) + 7 byte padding + sizeof(double) + sizeof(int) = 1 + 7 + 8 + 4 = 20 bytes but the sizeof(structc_t) will be 24 bytes.I didn't understood the alignment.Any one can help me?

Comment: This calculation is correct unless you pack the structures and you are on the 64 bit system which requires access to be aligned

Comment: sizeof(char) + 7 byte padding + sizeof(double) + sizeof(int) + 4 byte padding = 24

Comment: @zappy Why extra 4-bytes after last int?

Comment: @zappy Is it because for 64-bit and 32-bit systems the memory needs to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary?

Comment: The size needs to be 24 to ensure that the second element in an array is properly aligned.

Comment: @GauravPathak Do you understand why 7 bytes are padded after first char?  The largest type in the struct is double which is of size 8 bytes

Comment: @zappy Yes, I understand that. It's a bit unclear to me regarding 4-bytes padding after the last integer.

Comment: Got it. It is because of alignment rules `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374276/alignment-rules`.

Comment: BTW, where you have the choice, putting your fields in decreasing size order minimizes the padding (e.g., moving ‘c` to be after `s` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct looks like this, if we write it all out:

```
typedef struct structc_tag
{
   char        c;
   char        pad1[7];
   double      d;
   int         s;
   char        pad2[4];
} structc_t;
```

The `pad2` is what you don't want.  It comes into play because the compiler assumes you may want to make an array of these things, in which case every `d` has to be aligned, so `sizeof(structc_t)` is 24.

You can enable struct packing using a compiler-specific extension like this:

```
typedef struct structc_tag
{
   char        c;
   char        pad1[7];
   double      d;
   int         s;
} __attribute__((packed)) structc_t;
```

Now `pad1` is needed (otherwise `d` will immediately follow `c` which you don't want).  And `pad2` is no longer implicitly added, so the size should now be 20.

Comment: Does `__attribute__((packed)) structc_t` is used to avoid padding at the end of the structure?

Comment: @GauravPathak: Yes.  It also disables internal padding (which we add back in with `pad1`).